# Why are there two bearded faces wearing red hats on my stealth bomber icon?

Tags: freeciv

I was looking through the supported units of a city when I saw that my stealth bombers had two bearded faces wearing red hats in the bottom right of their icon. What does this mean?

[image: Freeciv Papua New Guinean stealth bombers]

Comment: @AlexMyers "This plane has 2 Santas of Delivery Power"

Comment: Alternatively, as victory markings; this plane has shot down two santas

Comment: @Chronocidal the naughty list needs a radical measures.

Comment: @VLAZ Krampus has offset his carbon emissions by switching from coal to uranium, eh?

Comment: @JLewis Impressive shooting for a bomber

Comment: @Yakk Bad case of road rage

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It makes two citizens unhappy.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Bombers, missiles, and helicopters (i.e. field units) are always considered "aggressive". Under a democracy, two citizens are made unhappy by each aggressive unit.

Comment: You can also look it up here, in the "Features of Governments" section: https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Government